# Trying to archive an instance of a class conforming to NSCoder

Tags: ios, json, swift, nskeyedarchiver, nscoder

I am working on my first Swift iOS app, having trouble serializing and saving an object whose JSON I fetch from the server. I am using [Gloss](https://github.com/hkellaway/Gloss), a lightweight JSON-parsing library which defines a Decodable protocol through which an instance can be instantiated from JSON. My intention is to load a thing from `JSON` (a type alias for `[String : AnyObject]`) by first extracting its id, and then check whether I already have a local archived copy. If I do, unarchive this and get the image. If not, make an asynchronous request for the image file.

The problem is that `Thing.localArchiveExists(id)` always returns `false`. Things are successfully instantiated but they always re-fetch the image. I have checked on the file system and confirmed that no archive files are being written. However, I am not seeing "ERROR. Could not archive", which suggests to me that the save succeeded. Am I missing something about how to archive and save NSCoder objects? Thanks!

Here is my implementation of the Decodable protocol:

```
// MARK: Decodable protocol
// When a thing is loaded from JSON, we load its image from archive if possible.
required init?(json: JSON) {
    guard let id: Int = "id" <~~ json else { return nil}

    if Thing.localArchiveExists(id) {
        guard let savedThing = NSKeyedUnarchiver.unarchiveObjectWithFile(Thing.archiveFilePath(id)) as? Thing else { return nil }
        self.id = savedThing.id
        self.name = savedThing.name
        self.image = savedThing.image
        self.imageUrl = savedThing.imageUrl
        super.init()
        print("Loaded Thing \(self.name) from archive")
    }
    else {
        guard let name: String = "name" <~~ json else { return nil}
        guard let imageUrl: NSURL = "url" <~~ json else { return nil}
        self.id = id
        self.name = name
        self.imageUrl = imageUrl
        super.init()
        dispatch_async(dispatch_get_global_queue(DISPATCH_QUEUE_PRIORITY_DEFAULT, 0)) {
            let data = NSData(contentsOfURL: imageUrl)
            dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(), {
                self.image = UIImage(data: data!)
                guard self.save() else {
                    print("ERROR. Could not archive")
                    return
                }
                print("Loaded Thing \(self.name) from server")
            })
        }
    }
}
```

Here are relevant parts of the Thing class:

```
// MARK: Properties
var id: Int?
var name: String
var imageUrl: NSURL?
var image: UIImage?

// MARK: Archiving Paths
static let DocumentsDirectory = NSFileManager().URLsForDirectory(.DocumentDirectory, inDomains: .UserDomainMask).first!
static let ArchiveURL = DocumentsDirectory.URLByAppendingPathComponent("things")

// MARK: Types
struct PropertyKey {
    static let nameKey = "name"
    static let imageKey = "image"
    static let imageUrlKey = "imageUrl"
    static let idKey = "id"
}

// Returns the file URL at which a Thing with the given ID should be saved.
class func archiveFilePath(id: Int) -> String {
    return Thing.ArchiveURL.URLByAppendingPathComponent("thing\(id)").absoluteString
}

// Checks whether an archived copy of a Thing with the given ID exists.
class func localArchiveExists(id: Int) -> Bool {
    let fileManager = NSFileManager.defaultManager()
    return fileManager.fileExistsAtPath(Thing.archiveFilePath(id))
}

// MARK: NSCoding
func encodeWithCoder(coder: NSCoder) {
    coder.encodeObject(name, forKey: PropertyKey.nameKey)
    if image != nil {
        coder.encodeObject(image!, forKey: PropertyKey.imageKey)
    }
    if imageUrl != nil {
        coder.encodeObject(imageUrl!, forKey: PropertyKey.imageUrlKey)
    }
    coder.encodeInteger(id!, forKey: PropertyKey.idKey)
}

required convenience init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
    let name = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.nameKey) as! String
    let image = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.imageKey) as? UIImage
    let imageUrl = aDecoder.decodeObjectForKey(PropertyKey.imageUrlKey) as? NSURL
    let id = aDecoder.decodeIntegerForKey(PropertyKey.idKey) 

    // Must call designated initializer.
    self.init(name: name, image: image, imageUrl: imageUrl, id: id)
}

func save() -> Bool {        
    // For some reason I can't archive to file.
    return NSKeyedArchiver.archiveRootObject(self, toFile: Thing.archiveFilePath(self.id!))
}
```

Comment: ... presumably `Thing` declares its conformance to `NSCoding`?

Comment: The problem is the struct inside your class. It is not coding compliant

Comment: @Tommy, yes, Thing is declared: `class Thing: NSObject, NSCoding, Glossy {`

Comment: @LeoDabus, I tried removing the struct, and I still have the same problem. Doesn't seem like the struct should be the problem, since I'm not encoding it. Any other ideas? Here's [the full class](https://github.com/cproctor/emoto_ios/blob/master/Emoto/Emoto.swift) if it helps. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I figured out my problem: the save failed because I had not yet created the directory in which I was trying to save my Thing.

```
func save() -> Bool {        
    let archivedData = NSKeyedArchiver.archivedDataWithRootObject(self)
    do {
        try NSFileManager.defaultManager().createDirectoryAtURL(Thing.ArchiveURL, withIntermediateDirectories: true, attributes: [:])
        try archivedData.writeToFile(Thing.archiveFilePath(self.id!), options: [])
        return true
    } catch {
        print(error)
        return false
    }
}
```